# How to access the selected option in an select tag with Django (not using Javascript)?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a form that has a select tag and dynamically created options for that tag as shown below. I want to access the selected tag if it is included in the POST request as part of the form in my Python/Django code:

```html
<form action="{% url 'newprogram' %}" method="post" novalidate>
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            TODO: Add Program to School
                            <select name="schooloptions">
                                {% for school in schools %}
                                    <option value="{{ school.name }}">{{ school.name }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input autofocus class="form-control" type="text" name="programname" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Post">
                        </form>
```

I want to select the option that the user selects from the drop-down menu as follows but it does not work:

```py
@login_required
def newprogram(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        programname = request.POST["programname"]
        school = request.POST["schooloptions"].selected() #This does not work and is what I need help with

        schoolobj = School.objects.get("school")

        school = Program(School=schoolobj, name=programname)
        school.save()

        return render(request, "network/index.html")
```

Any thoughts as to how I can access the selected option from a select HTML tag within a form?

Comment: what is value inside `request.POST["schooloptions"]` ?

Comment: Thank you for having me double-check this. doing `schoolname = request.POST["schooloptions"]` is exactly what I wanted.